# Why does it take so long to create a table?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I am creating the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE stats_by_site_tracking_hourly (
    d_tally text, -- 2016-02
    d_date timestamp, -- 2016-02-01 13
    site_id int,
    is_new_member int, -- 1/0
    device text, -- desktop/tablet/mobile/unknown
    tracking_medium text,
    tracking_source text,
    tracking_campaign text,
    tracking_term text,
    accepted counter,
    adjusted_accepted counter,
    rejected counter,
    adjusted_rejected counter,
    error counter,
    impressions_positive counter,
    adjusted_impressions_positive counter,
    impressions_negative counter,
    adjusted_impressions_negative counter,
    revenue counter,
    adjusted_revenue counter,
    reversals_rejected counter,
    reversals_revenue counter,
    PRIMARY KEY ((d_tally), site_id, d_date, is_new_member, device, tracking_medium, tracking_source, tracking_campaign, tracking_term)
);
```

When I run the statement, it seems that the first few columns are processed quickly however when it moves onto the counter columns it slows down more and more for every column.

I have left this statement running for 5 minutes and it still hasn't completed.

Could anyone offer some insight into this behaviour?

---

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmzSU.png) is what CQLSH looks like as the table is being created, and when the screenshot was taken it hadn't progressed for 20 minutes or so.

---

I just put the create table command into one line and it worked instantly.

```
CREATE TABLE stats_by_site_tracking_hourly ( d_tally text, d_date timestamp, site_id int, is_new_member int, device text, tracking_medium text, tracking_source text, tracking_campaign text, tracking_term text, accepted counter, adjusted_accepted counter, rejected counter, adjusted_rejected counter, error counter, impressions_positive counter, adjusted_impressions_positive counter, impressions_negative counter, adjusted_impressions_negative counter, revenue counter, adjusted_revenue counter, reversals_rejected counter, reversals_revenue counter, PRIMARY KEY ((d_tally), site_id, d_date, is_new_member, device, tracking_medium, tracking_source, tracking_campaign, tracking_term) );
```

Comment: " it seems that the first few columns are processed quickly however when it moves onto the counter columns it slows down more and more for every column" --> how did you measure the progress of schema creation ?

Comment: When I copy the schema into cqlsh, it pastes one line at a time and I am assuming that the pause on each column is because it is adding the column.
This is very much an assumption however I can't think of any other reason for the delay. I have added a screenshot of cqlsh in my question.

Comment: "When I copy the schema into cqlsh, it pastes one line at a time and I am assuming that the pause on each column is because it is adding the column" --> It is maybe because your SSH connection is slow. **cqlsh** does not send the CREATE TABLE query to Cassandra until it has the complete statement, **not line by line**

Comment: The SSH connection is fine, and is performant when running any commands through ssh or cqlsh. The only time I'm experiencing a slowdown is when creating big tables.

Comment: How large is your cluster ? How many nodes are there ? Schema agreement takes some time in very large clusters

Comment: "When I copy the schema into cqlsh, it pastes one line at a time and I am assuming that the pause on each column is because it is adding the column" No, that's not how it works. From `CREATE TABLE` to `);` is ONE big command. The table is created after the `);`, absolutely nothing happens before. Whatever is going wrong here is NOT a cassandra issue.

Comment: It is only a 3 node cluster. From investigation it seems that when running the command CQLSH eats 70% of RAM and is using 107% CPU on the server, slowing down everything.

Comment: I just ran the command in a single line with no comments and the query completed instantly. Could this be a cqlsh bug?

Comment: Seems like a cqlsh bug - perhaps parsing the SQL style comments ( `--` ).

Comment: The weird part is that the slowdown started when the counter columns were being ran through. Time seemed to grow exponentially for each column it cycled through.

Comment: Exact same behavior for me on my Macbook Pro with 8GB RAM and Cassandra22 installed by Homebrew. Another colleague on a PC same issue running it on Linux. Once the script appears to get to the set<varchar> type fields it grinds to a halt and takes 3-10 minutes per column to create. Strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I raised this bug here: [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11177)

This turned out to be due to the tabs in the schema. CQLSH was trying to autocomplete each time it came to a tab.

Comment: I didn't think this would still be around!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue on several computers and appears it's a bug in the cqlsh> interactive shell. If you execute the script from your terminal it will immediately execute:

```
> cqlsh -f your_cql_script.cql <hostname>
```

This runs immediately no matter what size tables and will save you LOTS of time.

Comment: I posted this as a bug to Datastax and it turned out to be cqlsh interpreting the tabs and trying to autocomplete! +1 for the work around though :).