# Is Cassandra table creation slow?

Tags: java, docker, cassandra, datatables, cqlsh

I've a Jar file that initialises my Cassandra database during which it creates ~13 tables. This file is being run by our tests where we start a Cassandra test container and use the jar to set it up.

But I'm surprised to see that each table takes ~1-2 seconds to initialise, totaling ~15 seconds. If I manually create one of these tables, using `cqlsh`, it takes ~100-120 ms.

Is there an explanation for this delay? Is there a work around?

I came across [Why does it take so long to create a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455968/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-create-a-table) but I don't have any tabs in my tables.

**Update**

The Java Code boils down to

```
cqlSession.execute( SimpleStatement.newInstance(query).setIdempotent(isIdempotent) );
```

which uses the `java-driver-core` version `4.14.1`. The `query` looks like

```
CREATE TABLE settings (key text, value text, PRIMARY KEY (key))
```

and took 1.125 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out in the `java-driver-core` there is a feature called [debouncing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/manual/core/performance/#debouncing). Here requests are accumulated over 1 second / an upper count before being sent to Cassandra. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/driver/internal/core/util/concurrent/Debouncer.java#L127).

There are driver config settings that can be used to control the debounce behaviour, which I set as

```
datastax-java-driver.advanced.metadata {
  schema.debouncer {
    window = 1 milliseconds
    max-events = 1
  }
}
```

in order to remove the 1 second delay. This is appropriate for my use case. But the change requires consideration depending on usage.

Answer (score 2):

Because Cassandra is a distributed system, when you create a table you need to make sure that changes are propagated to all nodes so schema will be in agreement. This is especially important when you use something like Java driver that by default uses round-robin policy, so different DDL statements could be sent to different nodes, causing schema mismatch errors.  You can find an example of how to do that correctly [here](https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/WhiteListPolicyExample.java#L41).

In `cqlsh` it's not the issue as it always uses the same connection to send all commands, so you won't get schema mismatch because schema versions are generated on the same node.

Comment: Is there a work around? In my test container docker setup, AFAIK, there's only a single node. Would that not bypass the issue above?

Comment: it really hard to say without the actual code

Comment: This might be too little context. But the Java code boils down to `cqlSession.execute( SimpleStatement.newInstance(query).setIdempotent(isIdempotent) );` and uses `java-driver-core` version `4.14.1`. Where `query` is the CQL statement to create a table. e.g. `CREATE TABLE settings (key text, value text, PRIMARY KEY (key))` which took 1.125 s to run.

Comment: As I remember, driver 4.x explicitly waits for schema agreement...

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'll need to investigate this further. Looks like there are some options available - https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.2/manual/core/metadata/schema/#schema-agreement